# Meaning of "save with swords for tickets"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I am unable to understand the phrase "save with swords for tickets". What is the meaning of the sentence?

> She will never attend Sunday-school or learn to vote **save with swords for tickets**.

Comment: I can guess, but for a real answer you're going to have to add some more context, by quoting some more from wherever you got that sentence.

Comment: All I get is she is uncivilized and will attack to go where she wishes.

Answer (score 2):

> ... Asia is not going to be civilised after the methods of the West.
>   There is too much Asia and she is too old. You cannot reform a lady of
>   many lovers, and Asia has been insatiable in her flirtations
>   aforetime. She will never attend Sunday-school or learn to vote save
>   with swords for tickets.

from [The Man Who Was](https://books.google.com/books?id=jkWtCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT37&lpg=PT37&dq=%22She%20will%20never%20attend%20Sunday-school%20or%20learn%22&source=bl&ots=JcOKlkeeRC&sig=NyK54dsJVPDwy8GXUWYC7TW1crw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizmrj_o_XTAhUlCsAKHRusAy8Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22She%20will%20never%20attend%20Sunday-school%20or%20learn%22&f=false) by Rudyard Kipling

***save with swords for tickets*** means: unless you replace voting tickets with swords.

Comment: I think "tickets" must be "ballots." // "Save" means "except."